# 4.1.8 Rails and 2.1.5 Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I get the "Welcome Aboard" page when my server is running?  I'm not getting the page on my computer on the local host site.  I'm using windows 8.1 and attempting to get to the page via internet explorer and not having success with other browsers. When I type "rails server" it states that "A server is already running".  I know I should get the welcome aboard page; however, I'm not having success.  I appreciate any assistance with this problem.

Comment: Since it says that "A server is already running" then you should try to shutdown that "stuck" server, probably via the task manager or maybe a full reboot.

Comment: I tried the reboot and it worked!!!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default the Rails server is on port 3000, so open `http://localhost:3000/` in your browser.

Comment: I was having trouble getting to the local host site but I tried a reboot and copied and pasted what you had and it worked!  Thanks man!